# State is not loading in my basic React/Redux App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I am working on the basic project from the Redux Documenation page. I am unsure the best way to put a redux project on Stack Overflow, so I instead uploaded my current progress to my GitHub page: https://github.com/davidreke/reduxDocumentationProject

I finished the instructions on setting up my reducers/store/action creators/ etc and got to the section of this page (h[ttps://redux.js.org/basics/store](https://redux.js.org/basics/store)) that says

> Now that we have created a store, let’s verify our program works! Even without any UI, we can already test the update logic.

However, when I tried making a blank page, I don't see any the console.logs that I have coded into store.js in my app folder, and I am unable to console.log(store.getState()). When I open up the Redux dev tool, I also see in there that there is no state. What am I doing wrong that no state loads in my application?

Edit: I've also never asked a question about an application that involves reduce and/or so many files, so if there is a better way for me to present my question, please let me know!

Comment: You have another store created in index.js. Also if you never import your store.js file anywhere, it is probably never bundled with the rest of the react app and thus never served. You probably want to include it in your react app with a Provider. Look at react-redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the store. In your `App.js` file import store and Provider then pass the store to the provider.

export store from `store.js`

```
export const store = createStore(todoApp)
// you can also add the store to the window object
// and use the console to play around with the data
//window.store = store
```

Then import store in your App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import {
  Provider
} from 'react-redux';

import { store } from './app/store';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <p>test</p>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```